# alignItems: 'center', not working on textInputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-stylesheet

I currently trying to make an app with react native and I have a problem with  the styling. I have textInput in the same View as a button  and I want to center them with `alignItems: 'center'` but it is not working for the text input :

Here is my code and what it is rendering :

```
  textInputAndButtonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 11,
    alignItems: 'center',
    },
```

[image]

And under you can see what I really want to do :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first remove `display: 'flex'`, so it is a default in rn stylesheets.
after that try to put into container style the next style values and check these.

```
      alignItems: 'center',
      contentAlign: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
```

Comment: It worked, thank you, I had to add an `alignitems : 'center'` to the textInput too

Answer (score 1):

from the code above, it is evident You didn’t specify if that is a className (.) or an ID (#)

Also, You could simply use the padding to bring the input to the center. See code below

```
.textInputAndButtonContainer{
    padding: 20px;
    align-items:centre;
    Justify-content-:space-between;
}
```

Comment: that's because I am on react Native, and if I add a padding it is just making the white box bigger (yeah that's weird)